# Elegant way to write criteria based if statements

Tags: java, algorithm, simplify

I'm trying to find an object in a list based on a set of criteria. The basic logic looks like this

```
for (objectx obj : list)
{
    if (object.property1 > criteria1)
        //accept object
    else (object.property1 == criteria1)
    {
        if (object.property2 > criteria2)
            //accept object
        else (object.property2 == criteria2)
        {
            if (object.property3 > criteria3)
                  ... etc
        } 
    }                                  
}
```

Is there an elegent way to simplify this mess?

Comment: Is SO indenting that wrong or are you missing parenthesis?

Comment: You should always put `Parenthesis` even for one statement lines to avoid ambiguity and doubt about the intended logic!

Comment: Do you mean "else if (condition)" where you wrote "else (condition)"? Note, fix spelling of elegant - it's wrong in title and last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean accept = false;
for (int i = 0; i < object.numProps(); i++) {
   if (object.prop[i] > criteria[i]) {
       accept = true;
       break;
   } else if (object.prop[i] < criteria[i]) 
       break;
   // loop continues only if object.prop[i] == criteria[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that checks all of the properties then inside your loop you can simply say:

```
for (objectx obj : list)
{
    if(checkProperties(obj))
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding methods named after your business logic may help. Then reading the code should read like english and the actual comparisons are somewhere else. It makes it easier to think about too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like I did before that can help. I wanted to search for objects in database with NHibernate like you did. I created Query object to collect every criteria entered by user . And When I set the related property on Query object I added this criteria like this.

```
public bool Archive
    {
        set
        {
            if(value)
            {
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Archive", true));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsFavorite
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsFavorite", true));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you just want to filter objects in memory. You can also use [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).